# RBM for collaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, collaborative-filtering, deep-learning, rbm

My algorithm RBM for collaborative filtering will not converge...
The idea of what I think RBM　for collaborative filtering is

1. initial w , b , c and random at [0,1]
2. For By User
   clamp data -> visible (softmax)

   Hidden = sigmoid(b+W*V)

   Run Gibbs on Hidden -> Hidden_gibbs

   Positive = Hidden*Visible

   Hidden -> reconstruct -> reconstruct_visible

   Run Gibbs on reconstruct_visible ->  reconstruct_visible_gibbs

   negative = Hidden_gibbs*reconstruct_visible_gibbs

   End for
3. Update

   w = w + (positive-negative)/Number_User

   b = b + (visible - reconstruct_visible_gibbs)/Number_User

   c = c + (Hidden - Hidden_gibbs)/Number_User

I have seen lots of paper or lecture, and have no idea where is wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy problem! Your description of the learning procedure looks fine. But, there's a lot of room for mistakes from the description to the actual code. Also, for CF, "vanilla" RBM won't work.

- How did you implemented the visible "softmax" units?
- Did you train your RBM with a "single-user" dataset, as recommended in the original work[1]?

There are 2 more details about weight updates and prediction procedure that are slightly different from vanilla's RBM

[1] Salakhutdinov http://www.machinelearning.org/proceedings/icml2007/papers/407.pdf

Comment: I have saw the paper, and i feel confused about update part. Does RBM update by batch of user? or single user?

Comment: Ideally, it's best to train one user at time. But, some works reported results training in a mini-batch fashion, like this: http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/handle/2268/74400

Comment: Hello Dan, any luck here? I've been training a RBM for CF using updates per user, but, if you update by small batches, it also works. Just remember that your learning rate, ideally, should be proportional to the size of your batch.

Comment: Hello Dan! my working implementation of this model: https://github.com/felipecruz/CFRBM Hope it helps you.